# Lodash filter ignore case

Tags: javascript, lodash

is there a way of case-insensitive filter with lodash? I tried this (see below), but this works only partly (when the user input is also lowercase). Another problem is here after one search all the characters are in lower case.

I want to filter regardless of how (lower case or upper).

```
 filter(q: string) {
    let query = q.trim();
    let searchData = [];
    searchData = clone(this.data);

    searchData = searchData.map((entity) => {
        entity.email = entity.email.toLowerCase();
        return entity;
    });

    if (query) {
        this.approverEntities = filter(searchData, (a) => a.email.indexOf(query) >= 0);
    } else {
        this.approverEntities = this.data;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This approach worked out great for me:

```js
this.approverEntities = _.filter(searchData, (a) =>  {return new RegExp(a.email, 'i').test(query)});
```

The one caveat is that if the `a.email` contains any special characters the regex expression will process it as regex tokens (*e.g. parenthesis, brackets, etc.*). This solution will handle special characters regardless...

```js
this.approverEntities = _.filter(searchData, (a) =>  {return a.email.toLowerCase() == query.toLowerCase()});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did a case insensitive filter while also only requiring a substring:

```
this.approverEntities = filter(searchData, function(a){
   return a.email.toLowerCase().indexOf((query).toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter), [method()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#method), and a case-insensitive regular expression:

```
_.filter(searchData, _.method('email.match', /foo/i));
```

Or, if the search term is dynamic:

```
const filterCaseInsensitive = (search, searchData) =>
  _.filter(searchData, _.method('email.match', new RegExp(search, 'i'));
```